# how to install emacs23 on Mac OSX without GUI

Tags: macos, emacs

What's the best way to install Emacs23 on Mac OSX. I want to launch it from the terminal, without any X-windows or other GUI business.

I tried http://emacsformacosx.com/ but that launches a Mac application. I just want the text-only version inside of Terminal.

Thanks.

Comment: OS X (at least, my copy) has emacs 22 already installed. Too old for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would think that any GNU Emacs would accept the `-nw` command line option; the http://emacsformacosx.com/ version included.

You can then use a shell alias or wrapper script to do that by default.

e.g. for bash, you could use `alias emacs="emacs -nw"` (and add it to your .bashrc file to make it persistent).

Comment: make sure you're using the right emacs. just aliasing to emacs -nw will probably use the default version that shipped. I added the following line to my bashrc/profile  
---
`alias emacs="/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw"`

Answer (score 2):

if you use macports:

`sudo port install emacs`

Answer (score 1):

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) has Emacs packages available.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/)

```
$ fink install emacs23-nox
```

Or install the general package (`emacs23`) version and invoke it with

```
$ emacs -nw
```

Comment: I think this is better than the alias suggestion because it doesn't install all the X11 deps. However, isn't emacs without a gui already built in on OS x* systems?

Comment: @Fred: It is, but the OP specified version 23. I don't have 10.6, but my 10.5 box has version 22.1.1 as the system emacs.